# Print driverless with cups

Tags: linux, pdf, printing, network-printer, cups

my goal is to print a generated testreport (pdf, 1 A4 page) to any 
network postscript printer ( The printer is not fix, 
it only has to be a postscript printer. I tried Brother HL-5450DN & Brother HL-5370DW ).

Problem:

I tried CUPS with raw queues, but the Brother HL-5370DW (postscript capable) only print blanks.

Question:

1. Is it possible to print the pdf driverless, more closer without ppd files ?
2. Can i use ipp/ipptool for this problem.

Environment:
embedded linux image (3.14) with build-in cups,

Best regards 
Lars

Comment: PDF does contain postscript commands, but it is not postscript. So convert the PDF to postscript, and try to print that with raw queues on postscript printers?

Comment: i tried to convert with ghostscript ( GPL Ghostscript 9.15 ) :

`gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=report.ps report.pdf`

but it prints only a blank on both printers.

Comment: Wrong postscript level? What postscript levels do the printer support? Do you have an example file that prints correctly?

Comment: yes i think so, more closer wrong postscript "mime-type". both printers support level 3. I tried a fileprinter of my vm ( cairo 1.14.2). this generate a ps that both can print.

Comment: is it possible to run this conversion via a cups filter/backend solution without a ppd file.

Comment: I don't know enough details about CUPS to hack around using it without a PPD file. Converting it up front is simpler. Very likely your "fileprinter" also used `ghostscript`, but with different options. In your place, I'd have a look a both postscript files and try to find out what detail the printer chokes on. Also, I'd try to find out what the "fileprinter" actually does, since it seems to be (more) correct.

Answer (score 0):

BrScript3 has some bugs, I think.
In some cases, gs -sDEVICE=pswrite works better than -sDEVICE=ps2write for Brother PS printers, I don't know why.